# What rules govern the ordering/sequencing of adjective/adverbial prepositional phrases?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositional-phrases

When writing a sentence, I sometimes get stuck with the order of prepositional phrases if there happen to be a couple of them in a series. I cannot seem to place them next to the part they intend to modify, which ruins the sentence. I googled this particular problem and watched a few YouTube tutorials, which, unfortunately, has confused the matter further. I want to keep it simple and find out whether there's a way to get it right.

Another problem I have with them is that I sometimes cannot decide whether they should be
 punctuated or not, to make things clear.

Just to give you a small example

> There was a great interview... 1) of Mary about her book 2) in NYT 3)
>   by John

I cannot put these phrases into their correct order, and punctuate if or where  necessary.

Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get away from your first sentence idea and say it simpler.

- John interviewed Mary about her book in New York. It was a great interview.

Comment: Sure, that works. But what if I _wanted_ to write it as one senetence?

Comment: Then you have to make your choice , because I normally avoid heaping too many additional indications at the end of a sentence.